# proper way to display css content if session is set

Tags: php, css, session, loops, isset

I am currently developing a site where a user has to be logged in in order to see their profile. If the user isn't logged in, the profile page redirects to the login page. If the user is logged in, well, they get to see their profile!

Without going into too much detail, here is how my code functions: if the session is set, run a loop to grab user data from the database and display it in CSS. If it's not, display no CSS content and redirect to the login page.

I feel like there is an easier way to do this. Right now I have most of my CSS embedded in my php loop, and the code looks sloppy doing it this way.

My question is, rather than embedding a bunch of html, divs, etc. inside the php loop, could I just require_once("profile_info.php") if the session is set? It's been a real pain converting html/css to be php friendly. Maybe there are other alternatives that I am overlooking?  Thank you. :)

**EDIT**

It's funny how one can make things more complicated that they really are!  Indeed, I was combining my CSS and PHP which really cluttered my code.  With a quick glance I got things working the way they should.  Thank you all for the replies. :)

Comment: CSS should not be generated on fly. That is missing the whole point of CSS.

Comment: Your use of the term "CSS content" indicates that you are not separating data and design. Your PHP should generate HTML markup. In most cases, the CSS that styles your design would reside in a separate static file. It would be helpful if you could post the loop code that you are talking about.

Comment: You should generate html with classes or ids with php and then have the external css file apply only styles to those classes or ids.

Answer (score 1):

Did you already considered using a template engine for PHP?

Some years ago I used [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) on one of my projects but it should be a ton on template engines out there.

Comment: You can write the same crap the a temlpate engine. Though this is a good suggestion, I don't feel it's helpful in this case... also, I feel these are quite relevant: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/then-a-miracle-occurs-cartoon.png

Answer (score 0):

for the last part of your question...

I think you should add the following at the very beginning of `profile_info.php` instead of `require_once` it

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit(0);
}
```